# Docker - unable to run AWS S3 commands

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cli

Just started docker `conda/miniconda3-centos7` but when went into container and installed `pip install awscli` and then did `aws configure` with default settings - can not run `aws s3 ls`.

Error:

```
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
```

On the same host where docker is running - I can run above command without issues.

Comment: What do you mean with "with default settings"? Do you have changed the credentials or just pressed enter? When you have a clean docker container the credentials might be empty so you have to set them first to the same credentials you are using on the host.

Comment: I just pressed Enter (default). What would be the way to set the same credentials as on the host (in an automated fashion e.g. when starting a container)?

Comment: There are multiple ways. The easiest might be to pass them as environment variables when running the container. Can't try it at the moment cause I'm on my phone but it should work.